# Supporting transactions in a custom DatabaseManager

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, ado.net, .net-3.5

Let's suppose we have the following custom DbManager (the only private member it has is a `string connectionString`):

```
public class SqlServerManager : DbManager
{
    public SqlServerManager(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString) { }

    public override System.Data.DataTable GetDataTableFrom(string query, string tableName)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(tableName);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            return dt;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }

        return dt;
    }


    public override object GetObjectFrom(string query)
    {
        return GetObjectFrom(query, 0);
    }

    public object GetObjectFrom(string query, int commandTimeout)
    {
        object result = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
                command.Connection.Open();
                result = command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public override void ExecuteNonQuery(string query)
    {
        ExecuteNonQuery(query, (SqlTransaction)null);
    }

    public void ExecuteNonQuery(string query, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction transaction)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection, transaction);
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

a) How is it possible to add some transaction support here?

Say, using a shared transaction (null or any) and a couple of `Begin\Rollback\Commit\Transaction()`?

Let's suppose we have no complex situation, and only one transaction in the same time is maintained by our class.

b) Is is maybe better to use something like this (in the example is a similar, but DB2Manager):

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // first connection Created/Disposed
    myDb2Manager.ExecuteNonQuery(mySql_1);
    // second connection Created/Disposed
    myDb2Manager.ExecuteNonQuery(mySql_2);
    // 3rd connection Created/Disposed
    myDb2Manager.ExecuteNonQuery(mySql_3);
    // commit everything
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second solution is indeed better.

Then your database managers don't need to know anything about the transaction.  As an extra advantage, the transaction will be a local one if you only access 1 database manager in the using block, but will automatically promoted to a distributed transaction if you access more.

Last, your code will be a lot cleaner than doing the transaction handling yourself.

Comment: the second solution finally does not work properly with IBM's DB2 for AS400 database...

Comment: Why wouldn't that work?  It works with IBM's DB2 for z/OS, which (as far as I know) uses the same client software.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to pass an instance of SqlTransaction to the ExecuteNonQuery method. you are executing ExecuteNonQuery() which will execute the query (update, delete or insert) as an atomic operation against the DBMS. so the ACID properties of the transaction are guaranteed. But you still can access the running transaction via System.Transaction class "Current" static property to get the current "or called also ambient" transaction.
the second approach you proposed is also fine but also can be replaced by your methods like this ExecuteNonQuery(mySql_1+mySql_2+mySql_3) if you are working with one connection to the database.